# Check if two columns are equal for all rows per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, equality, having

Assuming a DB like this:

```
Date | Attribute1 | Attribute2 | ... | AttributeN
-------------------------------------------------
1    | A          | C          | ... | ...
1    | B          | C          | ... | ...
2    | A          | A          | ... | ...
2    | B          | B          | ... | ...
2    | A          | A          | ... | ...
3    | B          | B          | ... | ...
3    | A          | A          | ... | ...
4    | B          | C          | ... | ...
4    | A          | A          | ... | ...
```

I am trying to find for which unique dates (they are actual `date`s in the real case but I don't think that matters), *ALL* elements of `Attribute1` are equal to their corresponding elements in `Attribute2`. The result for the example data above would be

```
Date
----
2
3
```

Because for each record that has `date` equal to `2` (and the same for `3`) , `Attribute1` is equal to `Attribute2`. `4` is not returned because although the last record in the sample does meet the criterion (since `A` equals `A`), the second last record does not (since `B` does not equal `C`).

I could not work out how to write this query, I was hoping for some aggregate function (shown as `ALL(...)` in the code below) that would allow me to write something like:

```
SELECT Date
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Date
HAVING ALL(Attribute1 = Attribute2)
```

Is there such a function? Otherwise is there a clever way to this using `COUNT` maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT [Date]
FROM #tab
GROUP BY [Date]
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Attribute1 = Attribute2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/408581)**</kbd>

> Otherwise is there a clever way to this using COUNT maybe?

Why not :) Version with `COUNT`:

```
SELECT [Date]
FROM #tab
GROUP BY [Date]
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Attribute1 <> Attribute2 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/408583)**</kbd>

Comment: This (the `SUM` solution) seems to be the fastest for my data out of the three solutions offered here

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this:

```
select Date from Test
Except
Select Date from Test where Attribute1 <> Attribute2
```

Comment: There is no need for `DISTINCT`. Check [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) `EXCEPT returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t output by the right input query.`

Answer (score 1):

The logic is easier if you turn it around. You want all unique `DATE` values where there *isn't* a row where `Attribute1` is different to `Attribute2`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Date] FROM myTable
WHERE [Date] NOT IN (
   SELECT [Date] FROM myTable
   WHERE Attribute1 != Attribute2)
```